# Laravel 5.6 - How to fetch last X guest names for room deal?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I can't figure out how to structure an efficient Eloquent query for the following scenario.

Users can stay in many locations like rooms, apartments, homes, so we have a polymorphic `stayable_locations` table, but we're only focusing on the room `stayable_type` of this table. When the staff clicks a room, we want to display all available room deals (if any are available from the `room_deals` table) and also the last 3 guests for each room deal (if any).

Trying to get this output from the following tables via eloquent:

```
Room 111 (desired output for room deals and guests below)
- Room Deal #1 -> Able, Kane, Eve
- Room Deal #2 -> Eve, Adam

------------------------------------------
$room = Room::where('id',111)->first(); // room 111
// Eloquent query, not sure how to setup model relations correctly
// To get last 3 guest names per room deal [if any] in an efficient query
$room->roomDeals()->withSpecificRoomDealLast3RoomGuestNamesIfAny()->get();
```

Here is the table structure:

```
stayable_locations table [polymorphic]:
id | stayable_id | stayable_type | room_deal_id | room_guest_id
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  |     111     |     room      |       0      | 3 (Steve no room deal)
2  |     111     |     room      |       1      | 1 (Adam room deal) 
3  |     111     |     room      |       1      | 2 (Eve room deal)
4  |     111     |     room      |       1      | 4 (Kane room deal)
5  |     111     |     room      |       1      | 5 (Able room deal)
6  |     111     |     room      |       2      | 1 (Adam room deal)
7  |     111     |     room      |       2      | 2 (Eve room deal)

room_deals table:
id | room_id | room_deal
-----------------------
1  |   111   | Deal A
2  |   111   | Deal B


users table:
id | name
------------
1  | Adam
2  | Eve
3  | Steve
4  | Kane
5  | Able
```

**UPDATE: Showing respective models**

**User Model:**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable {
    public function stayableLocations() {
      return $this->morphMany('App\StayableLocation', 'stayable');
    }
}
```

**RoomDeal Model:**

```php
class RoomDeal extends Model {
    public function room() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Room');
    }

    public function guests() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'stayable_locations', 'room_deal_id', 'room_guest_id');
    }
}
```

**StayableLocation Model:**

```php
class StayableLocation extends Model {
    public function stayable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function room() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Room', 'stayable_id');
    }
}
```

**Room Model:**

```php
class Room extends Model {
  public function stayableLocations() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\StayableLocation', 'stayable');
  }

  public function roomDeals() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\RoomDeal');
  }
}
```

Any idea how to get the desired output via an efficient eloquent query?

Comment: I deleted my answer, it turns out out Eloquent does not support this type of query. If you check the issues addressed by this pull request, there are some other solutions you could try: https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/4918. Good luck!

Comment: @jonasstaudenmeir I noticed your package here (https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit) but after installing it, I am not sure how to apply the model relations correctly to get the desired output of eloquent eager limited results (since a polymorphic relationship is in use here, it makes it a bit more challenging). Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried newUserName02's deleted answer (do you still have it somewhere?) in combination with the package? How is "last" determined?

Comment: Thank you guys! Figured it out with the solution below. Thanks for the guidance newUserName02 and the package @JonasStaudenmeir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out from the helping comments in my question. Here we go:

1. Laravel does not have this out of the box [(see here)](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/4918) so we'll have to use a third party package.
2. Install the [staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit) package per link directions and follow usage example.
3. This is what needed to change above [still used same defined relationship above for below `...`], just added the `use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;`:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable {
  use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
  ... 
}

class RoomDeal extends Model {
  use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
  ...
}
```

4. Working query with nested limit via eloquent, thanks to the commenters and package help:

```
$room = Room::find(111);

$deals3Guests = $room->roomDeals()                                    // query deals
                ->with(['guests' => function($query) {                // eager load guests
                    $query->orderBy('stayable_locations.id', 'desc')  // get latest guests
                          ->limit(3);                                // limit to 3
                }])
                ->get();
```